# use a variable in xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-config

I have the following xml in a .discomap file in a Visual Studio web application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <DiscoveryClientResultsFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Results>
<DiscoveryClientResult referenceType="System.Web.Services.Discovery.ContractReference" url="http://mywebserver/service/Service.asmx?wsdl" filename="Service.wsdl" />
<DiscoveryClientResult referenceType="System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryDocumentReference" url="http://mywebserver/service/Service.asmx?disco" filename="Service.disco" />
  </Results>
</DiscoveryClientResultsFile>
```

I want to be able to parameterise the http://mywebserver parts as this will change depending on the environment the project is deployed to.

I have successfully parameterised other parts of my web application with this line of code in my web.config file:

```
<add key="WebServerURL" value="http://mywebserver01" />
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible, to have a this file pick up the value of the WebServerURL from the webconfig appSettings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You simply set the .URL property of the service object in your runtime code:

```
    Dim svc As New SomeWebService
    svc.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSetttings("WebServerURL")
```

Comment: hey - thanks for commenting. i can update my webconfig to what you are talking about. are you saying that using AppSettings would effectively render the xml information redundant? so i wouldn't have to maintain them manually? that's the goal. if this is true then great.

Comment: i have the following in my code: 

Dim webservice As Pointer.WebService = New Pointer.WebService() and there is already an appSettings key... Pointer.PointerWebService value = "http://myWebServer/Pointer/WebService.asmx" .... are you saying this can be overwritten in my code behind? eg. Dim webservice As Pointer.WebService = New Pointer.WebService(); webservice.URL = *url from appSettings key in here*

Comment: Ok - so I have been playing about with this and I am looking for more advice. It would appear I don't need to publish this information at all. I am only consuming the web service once published. Am I right in saying the disco file and wsdl are just for localhost type operations?

Comment: The URL that's in the wsdl is not specifically relevant at runtime, that's correct.  The only purpose of the wsdl is to provide a definition of the web service, it's methods and properties.  In a deployment, you just need to set the .URL property of the service object at runtime.  AppSettings is probably the most logical place to store that value.

Comment: Perfect. I got this going a day or two ago and meant to come back and say thanks. You solution worked well for me.